# Игнорируется выполнение строчки кода

Tags: c

**Алгоритм роботы программы:**

1. Вводим с клавиатуры «K»;
2. Задаётся двухмерный массив 6х6, который находится по формуле: mas [i] [j] = i * K + j;
3. Отражается сумма 3 и 5 столбцов;
4. Если сумма не создана отображается соответствующее сообщение, если наоборот отображается их сумма.
5. Запрос на повторение расчета, если наж. *y* - расчет повторится, если нажать любую другую клавишу - программа будет завершена.

Написал 2 кода, но заканчивают своё действие, на строке, выдают ошибку - **Прекращена работа программы**:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

При нажатии любой клавиши.

Выкладываю 2 кода.

**Первый код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 0, i = 0, K, j = 0, mas[6][6];
    char c='y';
g1: printf("Enter <K> ");
    scanf("%d", &K);
    printf("Array=\n");
    while (i < 6)
    {
        i++;
        j = 0;
        while (j < 6)
        {
            j++;
            mas[i][j] = i*K + j;
            printf("%4d", mas[i][j]);

            if ((j == 2) || (j == 4))
            {
                s = s + mas[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    if (!s)
        printf("variable <s> not found");
    else
        printf("s=%d", s);

    printf("\nFor repetition calculation press <Y> and for exit with software press either button: \n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == 'y')
        goto g1;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Второй код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 0, i=0, K, j=0, mas[6][6];
    char c='y';
    while (c == 'y')
    {
        printf("Enter <K> ");
        scanf("%d", &K);
        printf("Array=\n");
        while (i < 6)
        {
            i++;
            j = 0;
            while (j < 6)
            {
                j++;
                mas[i][j] = i*K + j;
                printf("%4d", mas[i][j]);

                if ((j == 2) || (j == 4))
                {
                    s = s + mas[i][j];
                }
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        if (!s)
            printf("variable <s> not found");
        else
            printf("s=%d", s);

        printf("\nFor repetition calculation press <y> and for exit with software press either button: \n");
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что за бред вы написали?! Вы, вообще-то, человеческим языком можете пользоваться?! Что такое !"отражается сумма"?! Что означает "сумма не создана"?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, человек написал два кода, а вы придираетесь к таким мелочам!

Answer (score 2):

Берем отладчик и смотрим на стек:

```
#0  0x00007fff93bfb286 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x00007fff8c46542f in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x00007fff93dcebf3 in __abort ()
#3  0x00007fff93dcf4d1 in __stack_chk_fail ()
#4  0x0000000100000eca in main at main.cpp:83
```

Видим там `__stack_chk_fail`. Значит ищем, что могло повредить стек.

Можно делать это методом пристального взгляда в код. Но это не удобно. Проще использовать санитайзеры (sanitizers. не знаю, как по-русски сказать). Нам нужно отследить адреса, значит компилируем с соответствующей командой:

```
g++ code.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -g -fsanitize=address
```

Запускаем и видим:

```
./a.out 
Enter <K> 5
Array=
   6   7   8   9  10  11

  11  12  13  14  15  16

  16  17  18  19  20  21

  21  22  23  24  25  26

=================================================================
==1071==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff55df8980 at pc 0x000109e088d5 bp 0x7fff55df88b0 sp 0x7fff55df88a8
WRITE of size 4 at 0x7fff55df8980 thread T0
    #0 0x109e088d4 in main (.../a.out+0x1000018d4)
    #1 0x7fff8a97c5c8 in start (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x35c8)
    #2 0x0  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x7fff55df8980 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 192 in frame
    #0 0x109e085df in main (.../a.out+0x1000015df)

  This frame has 3 object(s):
    [32, 36) 'K'
    [48, 192) 'mas' <== Memory access at offset 192 overflows this variable
    [256, 257) 'c'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow ??:0 main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1fffeabbf0e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf0f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 04 f2 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1fffeabbf130:[f2]f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 01 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffeabbf180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1071==ABORTING
  26  27  28  29  30Abort trap: 6
```

Ура, обнаружили, что что-то не так с массивом `mas` (по секрету скажу, что это очевидно, так как других, мимо которых можно промахнуться, на стеке нет).

Ну дальше понятно: смотрим в код, видим там `while` вместо `for`, а инкремент в начале, а не в конце.

Ну или можно в том же отладчике отслеживать, куда что записывается, если ситуация не такая тривиальная.

Comment: Лично мне твой ответ пригодится, а так код написан под ДОС/виндовый компилятор и gcc там и близко не стояло

Answer (score 1):

У тебя сначала идет проверка `while (i < 6)` и сразу за ней ты увеличиваешь i на 1 и начинаешь с ним работать. Таким образом когда на начало цикла i=5 проверка проходит, цикл начинается, i увеличивается и работает с i==6 ! В итоге ты выходишь за границы массива. Кроме того ты из за этого начинаешь работу с i=1, а не с 0 с которого начинается отсчет в массиве.

Делай `i++` в конце цикла. С j то же самое разумеется

Comment: Ставил i++ и j++ в конец циклов, тогда вообще массив получается однострочный и сумма получается не та.

Comment: Ну логично что бы и тот и другой были в конце цикла. надо же что бы первый круг проходил с индексом 0. Ставлю обе к конец и матрица норм печатается, сумму лень проверять, но должна быть правильной

Comment: Также строку scanf("%c", &c) нужно заменить на scanf("%s", &c)